# color in ggplot aes within function

Tags: r, ggplot2

how I could specify the color in ggplot aes within function with the variable I pass to function?

1. when I assign color outside the function, I got the correct legend

```
    dat <- mtcars %>% dplyr::select(all_of(c("vs", "disp"))) %>% na.omit()
    colnames(dat) <- c("y", "x")
    dat <- dat %>%mutate("vs"=y)
    if(is.numeric(dat$x)){
    ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
        geom_point( na.rm = TRUE, aes(color = vs)) + 
        geom_smooth(method = glm, method.args = list(family = binomial), na.rm = TRUE, 
                    formula = y ~ x)+
        labs(x = "disp", y = "vs" ) +
        theme_bw()+
        theme(legend.position = "top")
    }
```

[image]

2. but when I do the same within the function, I got the wrong legend showing "y.." instead of "vs..":

```
      myplot <- function(data, x.name, y.name){
      dat <- data %>% dplyr::select(all_of(c(y.name, x.name))) %>% na.omit()
      colnames(dat) <- c("y", "x")
      # dat <- dat %>%
      #   mutate(y.name=y)
      
      if(is.numeric(dat$x)){
        p_plot<-ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
          geom_point( na.rm = TRUE, aes(color = y)) + 
          geom_smooth(method = glm, method.args = list(family = binomial), na.rm = TRUE, 
                      formula = y ~ x)+
          labs(x = x.name, y = y.name ) +
          theme_bw()+
          theme(legend.position = "top")
        
      }
      
      return(p_plot)
    }
    myplot(
      y.name = "vs", x.name = "disp",data = mtcars
    )
```

[image]

Comment: `help("embrace-operator", package = "rlang")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've changed the column names of the dataframe `colnames(dat) <- c("y", "x")` and this is the reason why the legend refers to this name. In the first example you've set legend names manually.

To make the legend name proper you can insert `colour=y.name` in `labs(x = x.name, y = y.name, colour=y.name )` and it should work.

```
myplot <- function(data, x.name, y.name){
      dat <- data %>% dplyr::select(all_of(c(y.name, x.name))) %>% na.omit()
      colnames(dat) <- c("y", "x")
      # dat <- dat %>%
      #   mutate(y.name=y)
      
      if(is.numeric(dat$x)){
        p_plot<-ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
          geom_point( na.rm = TRUE, aes(color = y)) + 
          geom_smooth(method = glm, method.args = list(family = binomial), na.rm = TRUE, 
                      formula = y ~ x)+
          labs(x = x.name, y = y.name, colour=y.name) + # << HERE
          theme_bw()+
          theme(legend.position = "top")
        
      }
      
      return(p_plot)
    }
    myplot(
      y.name = "vs", x.name = "disp",data = mtcars
    )
```

[image]